# Intersection Observer fails to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, intersection-observer

I am trying to create infinite scrolling with intersection observer, but callback function fails to update state. When i scroll down i can see states's console.log output but its always same.

````
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

// Css
import './index.css';

// Components
import QuadColors from './colors-components/quad-colors';
import SearchBar from '../../components/searchBar';
export default function colors() {
  const [renderColorSets, setRenderColorSets] = useState(5);
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const footRef = useRef();

  // Intersection Observer
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        setRenderColorSets(renderColorSets + 1);
        console.log(renderColorSets);
      }
    });

    observer.observe(footRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <SearchBar placeholder="Color" />
      <div className="random-colors-container" ref={containerRef}>
        {[...Array(renderColorSets)].map(() => {
          return <QuadColors />;
        })}
        <div ref={footRef} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should give an update function to setState, not an updated value itself (cause of enclosured value within observer callback function). Try to do next:

```
if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
  setRenderColorSets((prevColorSets) => prevColorSets + 1);
  console.log(renderColorSets);
}
```

Thus whenever you fire setState function - you have the latest value of state.

Comment: Thanks for your sollution Rowan. It works, i don't know how i overlooked it. Though the sollution works, the console.log below the state update still prints '6' which was the default state, can you please tell me why ?

Comment: @AshwinBhargava the problem that for observer callback you have enclosed state value. It's a value of the first launch. Callback remembers link to that specific value. But on the next render react gives another link to the next value. Thus you have a state where callback refers to it's own, outdated value.

To get `console.log` working you may put it inside of the updater function. Basically you may put there anything. There are 2 requirements. To return value should be stored in the state and to avoid side effects.